# Why isn't x *= 5 + 3 equivalent to x = x * 5 + 3?

Tags: javascript, python, programming-languages

If we let `x = 2`, and we perform `x *= 5 + 3`, the result is `16`, equivalent to if we had done `x *= (5 + 3)`, rather than `x = x * 5 + 3` which would be `13`.

I intuitively understand this, but a friend is wondering why `x*= A + B` isn't equivalent to `x = x * A + B`, when that is seemingly how `x+= A + B` works; `x = x + A + A`.

I'm trying to come up with a satisfying explanation for how things are working under the hood that makes this so, and why it was made to work that way.

Comment: *"equivalent to if we had done x *= (5 + 3)"* - It sounds like you already have an explanation, no?

Comment: right hand side comes first and then the assignment with the operator.

Comment: @David He's wanting to know why it implies parantheses around 5 + 3, as opposed to x = x * 5 + 3.

Comment: Because of operator precedence.

Comment: You seem to think `x *=` is simply a macro for `x = x *`. It is most certainly not in any sensible language.

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages. "Assembly" can mean a lot of assembly languages, and they generally won't support this syntax. There are many languages other than Javascript and Python that do have syntax like this. If you are asking about a specific language, tag just that; otherwise, consider using `language-agnostic`.

Comment: @MichaelMoreno: Your friend can simply use a reference on [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).  For any given assignment operation, the expression to the right of that operation is evaluated first.

Comment: @chepner That is how I've thought about it so far, and how many public guides explain it. If it's not just a macro for `x = x * b`, what's happening under the hood?

Comment: To a first approximation, `x *= b` in Python is implemented by `x = x.__imul__(b)`; the entire right-side is evaluated, and the result is passed as a single argument to the method. It's *not* just a syntactic transformation.

Answer (score 4):

The "compiler" knows to evaluate the RHS according to [PEMDAS/BODMAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) first before multiplying the value on the left, and in fact, just simplifies 5+3 to 8:

```py
dis.dis("x *= 5 + 3")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (8)     # <-- (5+3) = (8)
              4 INPLACE_MULTIPLY
              6 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

And doing multiplication before addition:

```
dis.dis("x = x*5 + 3")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (5)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

and addition before multiplication

```
dis.dis("x = 3 + x * 5")
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (3)
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (5)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Still results in the `BINARY_MULTIPLY` instruction of `x` and `5` before `BINARY_ADD` with `3`

Comment: The compiler optimization that precomputes `5 + 3` to `8` isn't really relevant to the question. You'll get roughly the same code with something like `x *= y + 3`, where you still need to generate code to add `y` and `3` before you can multiply that result by `x`.

Comment: @chepner I tried to explain that in the second two disassembles, but didn't do an in-place assignment example.

Answer (score 3):

Because of operator precedence. All the `<operator>=` operators have the same precedence as `=`, which is lower than the regular arithmetic operators. So

```
x *= 5 + 3
```

is parsed as

```
x *= (5 + 3)
```

for the same reason that

```
x = 5 + 3
```

is parsed as

```
x = (5 + 3)
```

rather than

```
(x = 5) + 3
```

The last isn't even meaningful in Python, because `=` can't be used in expressions, only statements. But you could replace it with the `:=` operator to get something analogous to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with assembly language and everything to do with language definition and parsing to that specification, as required by the language definition.

Your friend is splitting the * and = apart but they are one operator, not two.  As a result there is only a single precedence value for that entire operator.  We can't split these apart and then give each their own precedence!

While this kind of operator is a shortcut of sorts, it is a true operator, not a macro nor a form of textual substitution.

---

Consider for example, `a[i++] += x` or `a[f()] += x`.  While those are legal and ok, they won't necessarily work "expanded" as in `a[i++] = a[i++] + x`, which is illegal undefined behavior, due to two modifications to `i` within a single expression.